# disable radio button circle when another circle is chosen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a radio button element with YES and NO options. what I need is: when I click yes, it will disable NO option(which means I can't click it)
here is the code :

```
 <span class="value">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ReinstatementType, "1", new { @id = "yesReinstate" }) &nbsp;  YES &nbsp;
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ReinstatementType, "2", new { @id = "noReinstate" }) &nbsp; NO
    </span>
```

I tried to use getElementById but didn't work. also can I hide No option when I click Yes ?

Comment: Your question is about [tag:javascript] / [tag:jquery] - please provided the *rendered* HTML, not the [tag:razor] server-side code.

Comment: `I tried to use getElementById` please show this attempt. How didn't it work? Was there an error?

Comment: document.getElementById("noReinstate").disabled = true;

Comment: That looks like it *should* work, *in isolation* - but perhaps it's your event handler that's not working.  Ideally, please [edit] your question and add a [snippet] that demonstrates the answer (for which you will need the rendered HTML).  See [mcve].

Comment: Is that ASP.NET MVC ?

Comment: @PabloSalazar yes

Comment: Please add ASP.NET/MVC tags to your question

Comment: @PabloSalazar the question is not *about* asp.net/mvc, so should not be tagged as such.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a JavaScript function to listen for the change event on the "YES" radio button, and in the function, disable the "NO" radio button if the "YES" radio button is selected.
E

```js
 document.getElementById("yesReinstate").addEventListener("change", function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            document.getElementById("noReinstate").disabled = true;
        }
    });
```